# How to select word in TextBox with given screen coordinates?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an image of arrow, which follow the finger. When I lift finger I want to select a word in the TextBox under the end of arrow. So I have a screen coordinates in

```
imgArrow_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
```

event and have to fire

```
TextBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
```

to get right position for cursor in TextBox.

The question is how to `TextBox_Tap()` fired with given coordinates, because I can't construct `GestureEventArgs e` myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
input.getWordUnderPosition(x, y);
```

Comment: ha-ha... That function doesn't exist in c#!